How to change value of cell programmatically in @mui/x-data-grid
I get info of selected rows but want to change the value of selected rows (or particular cell ) on button click.
the targeted column is type of singleSelect and shows 3 options accepted, reject and pending.
Expected behaviour:

select few rows
click any one button accepted, rejected or pending (buttons are outside of table/grid. i.e. its above/below)
clicking on button should set the value for selected rows
[optional] it should trigger processRowUpdate event

Suppose i want to set value 'accepted' in the column 'Approval' of selected rows then I would click select few rows and then click the button accepted which is above the table.
      <Button onClick={()=>setApproval('accepted')}> Accepet </Button>
      <Button onClick={()=>setApproval('rejected')}> Reject </Button>
      <Button onClick={()=>setApproval('pending')}> Pending </Button>
 
      <DataGrid
        disableRowSelectionOnClick
        checkboxSelection 

        rows={rows}
        columns={columns}

        columnVisibilityModel={columnVisibility}
        onColumnVisibilityModelChange={handleColumnVisibility}
        
        // Editing
        processRowUpdate={handleProcessRowUpdate}
        onProcessRowUpdateError={(error) => {
          console.log('error in process ', error)
        }}

        // row selection
        rowSelectionModel={selectedRows}
        onRowSelectionModelChange={handleRowSelectionModelChange}
      />


I guess you need to update the data that the grid presents. If you create a working demo (using codesandbox or something) it might be easier to help
